# Ember-data 2: How to retrieve belongsTo model id without store fetching the record from the server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an `activity` model that belongs to a `report`. I have a scenario where I have only the activity records and all I want to do is get the `report` id, without fetching the whole record.

```
activity.get('report_id') // undefined

activity.get('report.id') // the id! But after a full fetch
```

Obviously, it knows the id, but I can't figure out the right incantation. Anyone have any thoughts?

ps. It looks like this changed in ember-data 2 so a previous answer will not work.

```
-------------------------------
Ember             : 2.4.1
Ember Data        : 2.4.0+9f8c40927a
jQuery            : 1.11.3
Ember Simple Auth : 1.0.0
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though locks answer was very helpful in understanding the direction this is going, it's not immediately practical. The RFC have a comment with a simple solution for right now.

1. Add a new id attribute to the model
2. Populate in the serializer

https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/57#issuecomment-121008369

```
//models/report-activity.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  report: belongsTo('report', {async: true}),
  reportId: attr('string'), //set in serializer
});

//serializers/report-activiy.js
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  normalizeAttributes(typeClass, hash) {
    if (hash.report_id) {
      hash.reportId = hash.report_id;
    }

    return this._super(typeClass, hash);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do it in the Release channel, but if you use Canary and enable the [`ds-references` feature flag](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/FEATURES.md#feature-flags) you can use features laid out in [RFC 57](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/ce19612e447e0ec393f842bfb31add96edaba9a1/text/0057-ember-data-reference-unification.md).

Comment: Thanks, @locks. If I were on canary, this would still be a confusing setup. I need the id in the template and it looks like I'd need to call it in a different way. I did find an example of how to do this in the serializer in the RFC comment thread: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/57#issuecomment-121008369. I'll post that as an answer